# every time I submit with a State, but there is an error, it doesn't save the state selected what Am I missing on the php script?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, validation, drop-down-menu

Im hoping someone can help me, there is probably a simple solution
I am writing a php form with twitter bootstrap as a framework and have created a dropdown. once the state is selected and the submit button clicked, but  "I am human" checkbox  is missing the error messages comes up and the state selected is not saved. how Do i get the state to save as well..

```
<?php

 if ($_POST['submit']) { 
 } 
  if (!$_POST['state']) {
       $error="<br/>-- Please enter a State";
 } 

  if (!$_POST['check']) {
       $error.="<br/>-- Please confirm your human";
  }   
 if ($error) {
    $result="Whoops, there is an error. please correct the following: 
    $error";
    }
 }
?>
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, 
 shrink-to-fit=no">

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" 
 href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"href="css/contact_form.css">
</head>
<body>
 <form method="post" action="#" role="form"> 
 <div class="col-md-3 offset-md-3">
      <div class="form-group">
       <select class="form-control" id="state" name="state" 
      placeholder="state" value="<?php echo $_POST['state']; ?>">
        <option value="">State</option>
        <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
        <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
        <option value="CA">California</option>
        <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
        <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
        <option value="DC">District of Columbia</option>
        <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
        <option value="FL">Florida</option>
        <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
        <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
        <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
        <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
        <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
        <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
        <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
        <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
        <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
        <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
        <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
        <option value="ME">Maine</option>
        <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
        <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
        <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
        <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
        <option value="MT">Montana</option>
        <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
        <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
        <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
        <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
        <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
        <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
        <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
        <option value="NY">New York</option>
        <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
        <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
        <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
        <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
        <option value="PR">Puerto Rico</option>
        <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
        <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
        <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
        <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
        <option value="TX">Texas</option>
        <option value="UT">Utah</option>
        <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
        <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
        <option value="WA">Washington</option>
        <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
        <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
        </select>
     </div>   
    </div>
   <div class="checkbox" id="options">
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" name="check"> I am human
            </label>
             </div>
    <div align="center">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" 
 value="send message"/>   
 </div>      
 </form> 

 <script src="js/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not set value for select this way

```
<select class="form-control" id="state" name="state" 
  placeholder="state" value="<?php echo $_POST['state']; ?>">
```

You should check every opion is select to set value

```
<option value="AK" <?php if ($_POST['state'] == "AK") {echo "selected";}?> >Alaska</option>
```

Comment: THANK you very much! i was thinking this was the solution